# SQL Join - Can't eliminate Cartesian results

Tags: sql, join

I'm not quite figuring out how to eliminate the Cartesian results I am getting in my join. I thought I had successfully created a subquery, but apparently not.
I am working with one table. I am attempting to create a column which reflects a previous year number, based off a transaction code of 50 and being written in the month of December.

Unfortunately, when I have a transaction 50 in any other month, I am getting a Cartesian result on that 50.

I thought that the Cartesian results were the due to being multiple matches with my 'On' criteria, so I really tried to limit that as you can see. It didn't work like I intended.

Here is my code - how do I remove the Cartesian results?

```
SELECT DataList.[State]
      ,DataList.[Symbol]
      ,DataList.[ClaimNumber]
      ,DataList.[AgentState]
      ,DataList.[Agent]
      ,DataList.[Adjuster]
      ,DataList.[Transactions]
      ,DataList.[WrittenDate]
      ,DataList.[EffectiveDate]
      ,DataList.[LossDate]
      ,DataList.[ReportedDate]
      ,sum(DataList.[Amount]) as Amount
    ,sum(EOYResvs.[EOYRESVAmount]) as EOYResvAmount
      ,DataList.[MajorPeril]
      ,DataList.[Class]
      ,DataList.[AmountCover]
      ,DataList.[DedAmount]
      ,DataList.[DedType]
      ,DataList.[Cause]
      ,DataList.[LossType]
      ,DataList.[EarthquakeDedPerc]
      ,DataList.[WindHailDed]
      ,DataList.[Territory]
      ,DataList.[County]
      ,DataList.[LocationState]
      ,DataList.[Zip5]
      ,DataList.[AdjustIND]
      ,DataList.[ClaimCode]
      ,DataList.[FileNumber]
FROM 
    [Database].[dbo].[Info] DataList
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
         [State]
      ,[Symbol]
      ,[ClaimNumber]
      ,[AgentState]
      ,[Agent]
      ,[Adjuster]
      ,[Transactions]
      ,[WrittenDate]
      ,[EffectiveDate]
      ,[LossDate]
      ,[ReportedDate]
      ,[Amount] as EOYRESVAmount
      ,[MajorPeril]
      ,[Class]
      ,[AmountCover]
      ,[DedAmount]
      ,[DedType]
      ,[Cause]
      ,[LossType]
      ,[EarthquakeDedPerc]
      ,[WindHailDed]
      ,[Territory]
      ,[County]
      ,[LocationState]
      ,[Zip5]
      ,[AdjustIND]
      ,[ClaimCode]
      ,[FileNumber]
     FROM 
         [Database].[dbo].[Info]
     WHERE
         DATEPART(MONTH, [WrittenDate]) = 12 
         AND [Transactions] = 50
     GROUP BY
         [State], [Symbol], [ClaimNumber], 
         [AgentState], [Agent], [Adjuster], [Transactions],
         [WrittenDate], [EffectiveDate], [LossDate], [ReportedDate],
         [Amount], [MajorPeril], [Class], [AmountCover], [DedAmount],
         [DedType], [Cause], [LossType], [EarthquakeDedPerc], 
         [WindHailDed], [Territory], [County], [LocationState], 
         [Zip5], [AdjustIND], [ClaimCode], [FileNumber]) EOYResvs
     ON datepart(Year, DataList.[WrittenDate]) - datepart(Year, EOYResvs.[WrittenDate]) = 1 AND 
      DataList.[State] = EOYResvs.[State] AND
      DataList.[Symbol] = EOYResvs.[Symbol] AND
      DataList.[ClaimNumber] = EOYResvs.[ClaimNumber] AND
      DataList.[AgentState] = EOYResvs.[AgentState] AND
      DataList.[Agent] = EOYResvs.[Agent] AND
      DataList.[Adjuster] = EOYResvs.[Adjuster] AND
      DataList.[Transactions] = EOYResvs.[Transactions] AND
      DataList.[EffectiveDate] = EOYResvs.[EffectiveDate] AND
      DataList.[LossDate] = EOYResvs.[LossDate] AND
      DataList.[ReportedDate] = EOYResvs.[ReportedDate] AND
      DataList.[MajorPeril] = EOYResvs.[MajorPeril] AND
      DataList.[Class]=EOYResvs.[Class] and
      DataList.[AmountCover]=EOYResvs.[AmountCover] and
      DataList.[DedAmount]=EOYResvs.[DedAmount] and
      DataList.[DedType]=EOYResvs.[DedType] and
      DataList.[Cause]=EOYResvs.[Cause] and
      DataList.[LossType]=EOYResvs.[LossType] and
      DataList.[EarthquakeDedPerc]=EOYResvs.[EarthQuakeDedPerc] and
      DataList.[WindHailDed]=EOYResvs.[WindHailDed] and
      DataList.[Territory]=EOYResvs.[Territory] and
      DataList.[County]=EOYResvs.[County] and
      DataList.[LocationState]=EOYResvs.[LocationState] and
      DataList.[Zip5]=EOYResvs.[Zip5] and
      DataList.[FileNumber]=EOYResvs.[FileNumber]
 Group By
        DataList.[State]
      ,DataList.[Symbol]
      ,DataList.[ClaimNumber]
      ,DataList.[AgentState]
      ,DataList.[Agent]
      ,DataList.[Adjuster]
      ,DataList.[Transactions]
      ,DataList.[WrittenDate]
      ,DataList.[EffectiveDate]              
      ,DataList.[LossDate]
      ,DataList.[ReportedDate]
      ,DataList.[MajorPeril]
      ,DataList.[Class]
      ,DataList.[AmountCover]
      ,DataList.[DedAmount]
      ,DataList.[DedType]
      ,DataList.[Cause]
      ,DataList.[LossType]
      ,DataList.[EarthquakeDedPerc]
      ,DataList.[WindHailDed]
      ,DataList.[Territory]
      ,DataList.[County]
      ,DataList.[LocationState]
      ,DataList.[Zip5]
      ,DataList.[AdjustIND]
      ,DataList.[ClaimCode]
      ,DataList.[FileNumber]
      Order by DataList.[ClaimNumber], DataList.[WrittenDate]
```

Output Data Sample

Here is a datasample. This output is perfect except for the cartesian results on the fields where the transaction code is 50. The amounts are wrong since they have been multiplied by the number of results from the EOYResvs query

````
WrittenDate EffectiveDate   LossDate    ReportedDate    Amount  EOYResvAmount   MajorPeril  Class   AmountInsurance DeductibleAmount    DeductibleType  Cause   LossType    EarthquakeDedPerc   WindHailDeductible  Territory   County  LocationState   Zip5    AdjustIND   ClaimCode   PolicyNumber

24   A  15360   24  4244    9524    50  12/31/2018  10/5/2018   12/1/2018   12/10/2018  5000    NULL    4400    815622  0   250 0   0   9   0   250 283 87  24  63462   NULL    NULL    522434      
24   A  15360   24  4244    9524    50  1/31/2019   10/5/2018   12/1/2018   12/10/2018  5000    5000    4400    815622  0   250 0   0   9   0   250 283 87  24  63462   NULL    NULL    522434      
24   A  15360   24  4244    9524    50  2/28/2019   10/5/2018   12/1/2018   12/10/2018  5000    5000    4400    815622  0   250 0   0   9   0   250 283 87  24  63462   NULL    NULL    522434      
24   A  15360   24  4244    9524    50  3/31/2019   10/5/2018   12/1/2018   12/10/2018  5000    5000    4400    815622  0   250 0   0   9   0   250 283 87  24  63462   NULL    NULL    522434      
24   A  15360   24  4244    9524    51  4/25/2019   10/5/2018   12/1/2018   12/10/2018  1432.38 NULL    4400    815622  0   250 0   0   9   0   250 283 87  24  63462   NULL    NULL    522434      
24  PA  15361   24  1338    9473    55  12/11/2018  8/9/2018    12/6/2018   12/10/2018  5   NULL    2900    786111  0   500 0   0   20  0   500 104 58  24  64658   P   NULL    125425      
24  PA  15361   24  1338    9473    55  12/13/2018  8/9/2018    12/6/2018   12/10/2018  162.5   NULL    400 786111  0   0   0   0   3   0   0   104 58  24  64658   A   NULL    125425      
24  PA  15361   24  1338    9473    51  12/17/2018  8/9/2018    12/6/2018   12/10/2018  832.94  NULL    400 786111  0   0   0   0   3   0   0   104 58  24  64658   NULL    NULL    125425      
24  PA  15361   24  1338    9473    55  12/21/2018  8/9/2018    12/6/2018   12/10/2018  162.5   NULL    5000    786111  0   0   0   0   20  0   0   104 58  24  64658   A   NULL    125425      
24  PA  15361   24  1338    9473    55  12/26/2018  8/9/2018    12/6/2018   12/10/2018  162.5   NULL    2900    786111  0   500 0   0   20  0   500 104 58  24  64658   A   NULL    125425      
24  PA  15361   24  1338    9473    50  12/31/2018  8/9/2018    12/6/2018   12/10/2018  12000   NULL    100 786111  0   0   0   0   1   0   0   104 58  24  64658   NULL    NULL    125425      
24  PA  15361   24  1338    9473    55  1/8/2019    8/9/2018    12/6/2018   12/10/2018  -162.5  NULL    400 786111  0   0   0   0   3   0   0   104 58  24  64658   A   NULL    125425      
24  PA  15361   24  1338    9473    55  1/9/2019    8/9/2018    12/6/2018   12/10/2018  605.55  NULL    400 786111  0   0   0   0   3   0   0   104 58  24  64658   A   NULL    125425      
24  PA  15361   24  1338    9473    50  1/31/2019   8/9/2018    12/6/2018   12/10/2018  948 12000   100 786111  0   0   0   0   1   0   0   104 58  24  64658   NULL    NULL    125425      
24  PA  15361   24  1338    9473    50  2/28/2019   8/9/2018    12/6/2018   12/10/2018  948 12000   100 786111  0   0   0   0   1   0   0   104 58  24  64658   NULL    NULL    125425      
24  PA  15361   24  1338    9473    50  3/31/2019   8/9/2018    12/6/2018   12/10/2018  948 12000   100 786111  0   0   0   0   1   0   0   104 58  24  64658   NULL    NULL    125425      
24  PA  15361   24  1338    9473    50  4/30/2019   8/9/2018    12/6/2018   12/10/2018  948 12000   100 786111  0   0   0   0   1   0   0   104 58  24  64658   NULL    NULL    125425      
24  PA  15361   24  1338    9473    55  5/3/2019    8/9/2018    12/6/2018   12/10/2018  12.6    NULL    400 786111  0   0   0   0   3   0   0   104 58  24  64658   A   NULL    125425      
24  PA  15361   24  1338    9473    50  5/31/2019   8/9/2018    12/6/2018   12/10/2018  52500   12000   100 786111  0   0   0   0   1   0   0   104 58  24  64658   NULL    NULL    125425      
24  PA  15361   24  1338    9473    50  6/30/2019   8/9/2018    12/6/2018   12/10/2018  52500   12000   100 786111  0   0   0   0   1   0   0   104 58  24  64658   NULL    NULL    125425      
24  PA  15361   24  1338    9473    50  7/31/2019   8/9/2018    12/6/2018   12/10/2018  52500   12000   100 786111  0   0   0   0   1   0   0   104 58  24  64658   NULL    NULL    125425      
24  PA  15361   24  1338    9473    50  8/31/2019   8/9/2018    12/6/2018   12/10/2018  1548    12000   100 786111  0   0   0   0   1   0   0   104 58  24  64658   NULL    NULL    125425      
24  PA  15361   24  1338    9473    50  9/30/2019   8/9/2018    12/6/2018   12/10/2018  1548    12000   100 786111  0   0   0   0   1   0   0   104 58  24  64658   NULL    NULL    125425      
24  PA  15361   24  1338    9473    50  10/31/2019  8/9/2018    12/6/2018   12/10/2018  1548    12000   100 786111  0   0   0   0   1   0   0   104 58  24  64658   NULL    NULL    125425      
24  PA  15361   24  1338    9473    50  11/30/2019  8/9/2018    12/6/2018   12/10/2018  1548    12000   100 786111  0   0   0   0   1   0   0   104 58  24  64658   NULL    NULL    125425      
24  PA  15361   24  1338    9473    51  12/5/2019   8/9/2018    12/6/2018   12/10/2018  932 NULL    100 786111  0   0   0   0   1   0   0   104 58  24  64658   NULL    NULL    125425      
24  PA  15361   24  1338    9473    51  12/10/2019  8/9/2018    12/6/2018   12/10/2018  616 NULL    100 786111  0   0   0   0   1   0   0   104 58  24  64658   NULL    NULL    125425      
24   A  15362   24  4244    9524    50  12/31/2018  10/5/2018   12/1/2018   12/10/2018  5000    NULL    4400    783722  0   250 0   0   9   0   250 283 87  24  63462   NULL    NULL    522434      
24   A  15362   24  4244    9524    51  1/24/2019   10/5/2018   12/1/2018   12/10/2018  1851.34 NULL    4400    783722  0   250 0   0   9   0   250 283 87  24  63462   NULL    NULL    522434      
24  PA  15363   24  1361    9519    51  12/11/2018  9/1/2018    11/29/2018  12/10/2018  1309.5  NULL    2900    783223  0   500 0   0   20  0   500 245 10  24  65203   NULL    NULL    107908      
24  PA  15363   24  1361    9519    51  12/17/2018  9/1/2018    11/29/2018  12/10/2018  152.69  NULL    2900    783223  0   500 0   0   20  0   500 245 10  24  65203   NULL    NULL    107908      
24  PA  15364   24  3359    9431    55  12/14/2018  9/26/2018   12/7/2018   12/10/2018  177 NULL    4800    700720  0   500 0   0   9   0   500 290 42  24  64740   A   NULL    117274      
24  PA  15364   24  3359    9431    51  12/27/2018  9/26/2018   12/7/2018   12/10/2018  4972.52 NULL    4800    700720  0   500 0   0   9   0   500 290 42  24  64740   NULL    NULL    117274      
24  PA  15364   24  3359    9431    52  2/11/2019   9/26/2018   12/7/2018   12/10/2018  1324    NULL    4800    700720  0   500 0   0   9   0   500 290 42  24  64740   NULL    NULL    117274      
```
````

Comment: What is the table's unique key?

Comment: There is a SequenceNumber field, but that field isn't relevant where this resulting data set will be used.

Comment: Okay, then explain exactly what you are trying to show. Every single row of the table along with the sum of `EOYRESVAmount` for the same county? Or the same ClaimNumber? Or what else?

Comment: Sure! I am trying to show every row of the table with the sum of EOYResvAmount where all of the criteria match ClaimNumber, Majorperil, FileNumber, Agent, etc
where the Transactions of the original list is 50

Comment: Let me see if I got this. You show all rows of the table. For each row you find all rows that are exact duplicates (except for the WrittenDate and Transaction that must be month 12 and value 15 instead) and sum up their EOYRESVAmount. Yes?

Comment: Almost. transaction code is 50. 
You have the month correct, 12.
I forgot to specify in the text (can see it in the code) that the 12th month is for the prior year.
So, if I am looking at January, February, and March of 2020, I need to return EOYResv sum corresponding to 12th month of 2019 for all the matching criteria.

if I was looking at any of the months in 2018, I would return the corresponding EOYResv sum corresponding to the 12th month of 2017 for all the matching criteria.

I tried:
```
datepart(Year,DataList.[WrittenDate])-datepart(Year,EOYResvs.[WrittenDate])=1

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) [ask] For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization. PS This isn't minimal data. Likely not code either.

Comment: When you get a result that you don't expect/understand, stop trying to find your overall goal & find out what your misunderstanding is.--Isolate the first unexpected/misunderstood subexpression & its input & output & learn what misconception, typo, wrong reasoning, etc led to it. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is strange criteria on which you join. This seems to be caused by your table being too generic. It's called info because it is neither tranaction nor claim nor file, but can contain one thing or the other or even something combined? This makes it hard to query the data.

It seems you want to get something like this:

```
SELECT
  i.*,
  isum.sum_eoyresvamount
FROM database.dbo.info i
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT
    <all columns except for WrittenDate and Transactions>,
    DATEPART(YEAR, writtenDate) AS written_year,
    SUM(eoyresvamount) AS sum_eoyresvamount
  FROM database.dbo.info
  WHERE DATEPART(MONTH, writtenDate) = 12 
    AND transactions = 50
  GROUP BY <all columns except for WrittenDate and Transactions>
) isum ON isum.written_year = DATEPART(YEAR, i.writtendate) - 1
      AND isum.state = i.state
      AND <compare all other columns except for WrittenDate and Transactions>
ORDER BY i.claimnumber, i.writtendate;
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt!!! I'm getting the message:
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near '<'.

Comment: This is a placeholder of course. You are supposed to put all your columns there except for `WrittenDate` and `Transactions`.

Comment: This was almost perfect. The sum_eoyresv is appearing on records that also have transaction code other than 50 in the original table. I only need to have a value appear when there is a transaction code of 50. 
I tried to add isum.[Transactions]=i.[Transcations] , but that seemed to produce less than desireable results.

Comment: Oh, sorry. So, you want to sum up *all* `EOYRESVAmount`, not just those with `Transactions` = 50. But you want to do this only for original rows with `Transactions` = 50. So remove `AND transactions = 50` from the subquery (so as to add up all transactions) and add `AND i.transactions = 50` to the `ON` clause (so as to join the sum only on rows with transaction 50).

Comment: You were spot on with the summing of EOYRESVAmount. I only need to sum EOYRESVAmount where there is a transaction code of 50. 
When I go to make the results of EOYRESVAmount appear in the final list, it only needs to be on rows that also have a transaction code of 50.

Comment: Then leave `AND transactions = 50` in.

Comment: Looks like you got me there. Thanks a ton Thorsten. Answer marked!